# Google Analytics iOS SDK 3.0.8 IDFA App Store rejection

Tags: ios, google-analytics, appstore-approval

My app was rejected because it uses IDFA and it's not serving ads.
Apple told me to remove any instances of advertisingIdentifier, that means remove GA.

Is it really necessary to remove GA? If not, how do I get my app past Apple's review?

Comment: Short way for solving your problem: put ads into your app, that may be activated or deactivated. They could be activated e.g. for some weeks or via server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog):

> The SDK will now collect IDFA and the advertiser tracking enabled flag
>   if the library libAdIdAccess.a (provided as part of the SDK) is
>   included in the application and the allowIDFACollection property is
>   set to true on the tracker.

Alternatively, use [version 3.0.7](https://dl.google.com/googleanalyticsservices/GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.07.zip).

Comment: Now i am using google analytics SDK 1.0. What should i give in iTuneConnect "Advertising Identifier" option.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `libAdIdAccess.a` and `AdSupport.framework` which will be in GA SDK. These two are optional

files. :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features